# How do you finding a Attribute on a Method named in an Exception's StackTrace

Tags: c#, exception, .net-core, attributes

This is not trying to find a method name using Method Info. I already have the method name.

The business wants a log with all the exceptions recorded. They also want each exception to have some sort of logical ID. So ops can search the documentation for ID "BusinessRule2319Violated". We also have more general type failures of course "RegisteringClientFailed".

For the specific Exceptions like the violation of a business rule we populate the Data property with the ID. Not a problem. But for more general exceptions like something unaccounted for in Registering the client threw an exception I don't want to pepper my code with hundreds / thousands of try / catches to assign a unique code.

I am thinking of decorating methods with a kind of attribute like `[DefaultExceptionCodeAttribue("RegisteringClientFailed")` then in the Middleware or some global exception handler crawl the `e.StackTrace` and find the attribute.

I've gotten as far as code that find the name of the class and method from the `StackTrace`, but I can't figure out how to turn that into a `MethodInfo` to start checking attributes.

I can sometimes use `Type.GetType(string)` and get something, but other times it returns null, for the same type, depending on where I call it.

I feel like I am just missing an easy way to do this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't see how you managed to get method name without MethodInfo... Showing hwo you managed not to find what you need from `StackFrame.GetMethod` could help..

Comment: He got the method name from a log. Now he wants to create a MethodInfo to get the attributes of that method. So he needs to create the declaring type of that method - also from strings,.`Type.GetType(string)` is basically the right approach...
But depending on the assemblies loaded, the type's string rerpresentationneeds to include the assembly name or not.

Comment: I think you need to create the Type from the string returned by `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` to be fail-safe. E.g.
`var type = Type.GetType("System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");`
The short version `var type = Type.GetType("System.String");` might fail under some circumstances (through I don't the exact internals rules for that).